# can't list column data from one to many relation on sql with 3 JOINs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, one-to-many

I have 4 tables -

```
    CREATE TABLE `group_user` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `accepted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `group_table` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `groupName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `owner` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `date_dreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `training` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `groupName` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `sessDate` date NOT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `session_plan` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `training_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `workout_id` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`group_table` holds id and name of each group,

`group_user` holds which users are members of which groups,

`training` holds the id's and dates of sessions and what group they belong to

`session_plan` holds the individual workouts for a particular session on any given date. The workout id's are from a table called `workout_title` which is below and holds the names of the workouts, I have listed it below but for now am just trying to get a list of the `workout_id`

There could be many results from `session_plan` that match a single result for the other 3 tables.

I did have this set as a comma separated list but got told to normalise my tables,

while this did solve some of the other problems I had, I now have an issue where for every result in `session_plan` it will repeat the previous result and then just add on the next item from `session_plan`.

The code I have so far is

```
    $accepted = true;
    $ps = $db_conx->prepare("
        SELECT u.group_id
              , g.groupName
              , t.sessDate
              , s.workout_id
        FROM group_user u
        JOIN group_table g
             ON u.group_id = g.id
        JOIN training t
             ON g.groupName = t.groupName
        JOIN session_plan s
             ON t.id = s.training_id
        WHERE g.user_id = ? 
          && u.accepted = ?
    ");
    
        $ps->bind_param("ii", $id, $accepted); 
        $ps->execute();
        $result = $ps->get_result();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $testGroupName = $row['groupName'];
        $testGroupId = $row['group_id'];
        $testSessDate = $row['sessDate'];
        $testPlan = $row['workout_id'];

        $workout_plan .= " + " .$testPlan;

        $testSession .= $testGroupId. " : " .$testGroupName. "<br/>" .$testSessDate. " - " .$workout_plan. "<br/>";
    }
```

`$id` is defined further up the page.

What I would be looking for is something like :

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-05 - + 1 + 2

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-04 - + 4

But instead I get:

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-05 - + 1

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-05 - + 1 + 2

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-04 - + 1 + 2 + 4

I am new to normalisation and table JOINs so am not sure if I am using one or the other incorrectly or both.

I have searched for an answer on here and while there are similar I couldn't find one that fixed my problem often in a coding language I couldn't understand.

Logically I think the problem is the while loop will only pick one result from each table each time it passes through and then `$workout_plan .= " + " .$testPlan;` is storing that for the next run through the loop, I tried adding `$workout_plan = "";` and `unset($workout_plan)` outside the loop but just got the same result. If I remove `$workout_plan .= " + " .$testPlan;` the result looks like:

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-05 - 1

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-05 - 2

1 : TheBestGroup
2020-12-04 - 4

I'm just not sure how to get all the relevant entries from `session_plan` per each row for the others.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql. But as a 'heads-up', (while I appreciate the necessity to avoid reserved words) from my experience of naming tables 'something_table', things start getting really tedious really quickly

Comment: thanks @Strawberry please can you give me some clarification on starting with the sql though, I see you edited my code so do you mean my syntax was wrong? or do you mean the logic of the SELECT needs rethinking? ie if I used a different type of JOIN maybe?

Comment: I have edited the question now to include the sql for each of the tables so it can be replicated as requested, sorry it took me so long I was away with no internet for the week.

Comment: You should focus on the specific aspect which you are struggling with.  That appears to be a PHP issue; if you have a set of data with multiple dates and multiple values per date, what code is needed to collapse the data to one row per date?  That has *nothing* to do with the SQL.  This means that you can simplify your question by removing the SQL completely and focussing on just the PHP loop that processes the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need logic to differentiate between when you want to add a `workout_id` to a `testSession`, and when you've moved on to a new group or date.

Something like...

```
$testGroupId = "";
$testSessDate = "";
$testSession = "";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  // If this row's Group and Date are the same as the preceding row...
  // - Add this row's WorkoutId to the testSession and move to the next row

  if (($testGroupId == $row['group_id']) && ($testSessDate == $row['sessDate']))
    $testSession .= " + " .$row['workout_id'];
    continue;


  // If this row's Group or Date are Different from the preceding row...
  // - Add a break to the end of the previous testSession
  // - Do something with the previous testSession
  // - Start a new testSession with the current row's values

  $testSession .= "<br/>";
  # Code to use the previous testSession goes here

  $testGroupName = $row['groupName'];
  $testGroupId = $row['group_id'];
  $testSessDate = $row['sessDate'];
  $testPlan = $row['workout_id'];

  $testSession = $testGroupId. " : " .$testGroupName. "<br/>" .$testSessDate. " - " .$testPlan. "<br/>";

}

// The very last Group/Date combination won't have been processed by the While loop
// So, process it here

$testSession .= "<br/>";
# Code to use the previous testSession goes here
```